# Excel VBA - Going through filtered table and re-validating a second time after user has adjusted their entries - Logically won't work

Tags: excel, vba

So long story short, I have a user enter data, goes through a bunch of cleansing, validating macros and then presents filtered data containing errors with the data. The user either then fixes the errors with the information, or clears the contents of the cells with errors( which is clearly laid out for them to do). My issue is, when they clear the contents of the cells, I still have errors being returned when they run the re-validate macro (issues with blank spaces in the row). Here is my code, I can't get the isempty conditional to be true no matter what I do

```
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim cl As Range, rnger As Range

lastrow = Sheets("losses").Cells(Rows.count, "AM").End(xlUp).row

Set rnger = Range("AN3:AN" & lastrow)

For Each cl In rnger.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    x = cl.row
    Range("AA" & cl.row, "AN" & cl.row).Interior.Color = xlNone
    Range("AK" & cl.row, "AN" & cl.row).ClearContents

        If IsEmpty(Range("AA" & x, "AN" & x)) = True Then

        Range("AK" & cl.row, "AN" & cl.row).ClearContents

    Else

        Sheets("losses").Range("AK" & cl.row).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AB" & cl.row & ",References!$C$1:$D$41,2,FALSE),0)"

        Sheets("losses").Range("AL" & cl.row).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AE" & cl.row & ",References!$I$1:$J$13,2,FALSE),0)"

        Sheets("losses").Range("AM" & cl.row).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AF" & cl.row & ",References!$F$1:$G$116,2,FALSE),0)"

    End If

Next cl
```

Tried this method as well to no luck

Set rnger = Sheets("losses").Range("AN3:AN" & lastrow)

```
For Each cl In rnger.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        'If IsEmpty(Range("AA" & x, "AN" & x)) = True Then

        'Range("AK" & cl.row, "AN" & cl.row).ClearContents

    'Else

        Sheets("losses").Range("AK" & cl.row).Formula = "=if(countblank(AA" & cl.row & ":AJ" & cl.row & ")=10," & vbNullString & ",(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AB" & cl.row & ",References!$C$1:$D$41,2,FALSE),0)))"


        Sheets("losses").Range("AL" & cl.row).Formula = "=if(isBlank(AND(AA" & cl.row & ",AB" & cl.row & ",AC" & cl.row & ",AD" & cl.row & ",AE" & cl.row & ",AF" & cl.row & ",AG" & cl.row & ",AH" & cl.row & ",AI" & cl.row & ",AJ" & cl.row & "))," & vbNullString & ",(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AE" & cl.row & ",References!$I$1:$J$13,2,FALSE),0)))"

        Sheets("losses").Range("AM" & cl.row).Formula = "=if(isBlank(AND(AA" & cl.row & ",AB" & cl.row & ",AC" & cl.row & ",AD" & cl.row & ",AE" & cl.row & ",AF" & cl.row & ",AG" & cl.row & ",AH" & cl.row & ",AI" & cl.row & ",AJ" & cl.row & "))," & vbNullString & ",(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AF" & cl.row & ",References!$F$1:$G$116,2,FALSE),0)))"

    'End If

Next cl
```

Comment: You've already done clear contents before the IF so why are you doing it again? Also you set x = to cl.row but then never use it?

Comment: There are still snippets in there when I was going line by line to see where it broke.  You're absolutely right no need for the x and clear.contents before the if statement.  My main issue is why I can't get that IsEmpty function to output True

Comment: Try `Isblank` - see what happens there?

Comment: (Be sure to add the sheet you expect this to be on, `Range("AN3:AN" & lastrow)`)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it

```
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim cl As Range, rnger As Range

lastrow = Sheets("losses").Cells(Rows.count, "AM").End(xlUp).row

Set rnger = Sheets("losses").Range("AN3:AN" & lastrow)

For Each cl In rnger.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        Sheets("losses").Range("AK" & cl.row).Formula = "=if(countblank(AA" & cl.row & ":AJ" & cl.row & ")=10,"""",Iferror(VLOOKUP($AB" & cl.row & ",References!$C$1:$D$41,2,FALSE),0))"

        Sheets("losses").Range("AL" & cl.row).Formula = "=if(countblank(AA" & cl.row & ":AJ" & cl.row & ")=10,"""",Iferror(VLOOKUP($AE" & cl.row & ",References!$C$1:$D$41,2,FALSE),0))"

        Sheets("losses").Range("AM" & cl.row).Formula = "=if(countblank(AA" & cl.row & ":AJ" & cl.row & ")=10,"""",Iferror(VLOOKUP($AF" & cl.row & ",References!$C$1:$D$41,2,FALSE),0))"

Next cl
```